# What Could Cause System Apps to Run that Are Not Used

Tags: motorola-droid-razr, dlna, system-apps

When testing a widget I created, I wanted to make sure that it uses as little CPU power as possible. After some research I downloaded [Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomut.watchdoglite&hl=en) to use as a monitoring tool, which works great. When I finished my testing I set the CPU threshold at 10%, just curious to see what process would randomly go above that level. One that exceeds the 10% threshold on a daily basis, at least a couple times a day, is **`com.motorola.Dlna`**.

I know what [DLNA](http://www.dlna.org/) is, what it's used for, and how to set it up but I don't use it, nor do I have it set up on my phone. I spoke with a Motorola support analyst and asked why it would be running. The response I got was "it's possible you could have set it up without knowing it, maybe by an application that you downloaded but it's nothing to worry about".

Needless to say the answer I got wasn't very helpful so I'm really just wondering what would cause this service to use so much CPU power randomly? Most of the time it's not being used, but when it is, it shows that it's using usually between 12.5% - 15% CPU power. Do applications really access/use this service without me ever actually going through and setting it up?

Comment: I imagine the CPU usage is just that service doing its' routine functions (perhaps monitoring or surveying for surrounding available DLNA devices and the like), then going back to sleep. This doesn't necessarily mean any other app is using it.

Comment: @Namuna thanks for the input! Do you happen to know if using that much CPU power is normal for this service? Maybe it's just me but it seems really high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use some package inspector like e.g. [App Detective](http://de.appbrain.com/app/app-detective/com.zmarties.detective) to see what receivers the app in question has set up. Most likely it's acting on some broadcast, such as e.g. "sdcard mounted", to check for media, or "network changed" to check for other DLNA services.

If your device is rooted, you might be interested in apps like [ROM Toolbox](http://de.appbrain.com/app/rom-toolbox-lite/com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox) or [Autorun Manager](http://de.appbrain.com/app/autorun-manager/com.rs.autorun), which allow you to disable selected receivers, or even freeze the entire app. Without root, you can try whether that app can be disabled in *Settings → Apps*. It's either running for nothing or (these days it's no longer called "paranoia") working for somebody else, if you don't use it yourself.

Comment: Haven't seen App Detective before, so since my device is not rooted I'll definitely check it out. And yes, these days there's always a chance it isn't paranoia :) and that's why I asked! Unfortunately I don't have 15 rep on AE yet or else I'd upvote but as soon as I do I'll make sure I do. Really appreciate the help though!

Comment: Without root you can only check what's causing it, but hardly do anything to avoid it (unless the system lets you disable that app). But as written, it's most likely some event listener. Same with Google Music, Google Maps, and others: I rarely use maps, and never the Music app, so they always are the first things I disable/freeze.